# How to extend django User model properly

Tags: django, authentication

Here i am trying to add profile model fields along with user model fields.But it not working it doesn't add the profile models data.But `after adding` when i do update the user i can update both model `user` and `profile` together.But while registering the user i am not being able to add `profile` models data .Is it possible to add profile model data along with user model at a time ?

> models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user image',default='default.jpg')


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

> forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False)
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
    image = forms.FileField(required=False, initial='default.jpg')

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise ValidationError('Email Already Exists')

        return email

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', "email", "password1", "password2",'first_name','last_name','location','phone','image','is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active']
```

> views.py

```
def add_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, 'user created with username {}'.format(user.username))
            return redirect('list_user')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'add_user.html', {'form': form})

def update_user(request, id): #the problem while  updating is if i don't select the new image then it saves the default image.But other works fine
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = EditRegisterForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None,instance=user)
        if form.is_valid():
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            location = form.cleaned_data['location']
            image = form.cleaned_data['image']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.profile.phone = phone
            user.profile.location = location
            user.profile.first_name = first_name
            user.profile.last_name = last_name
            user.profile.image = image
            user.save()
            messages.success(request, ' {}  updated.'.format(user.username))
            return redirect('list_user')
```

> add_user.html

```
 <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                             {% bootstrap_form form %}
                            <div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to this with your own logic,
consider using the @transaction.atomic decorator in your view.

Nothing will get saved into your DB if anything raises an exception
doc here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic

You can then simply do this:

````
# remove your signals first, they're not required if you manually create the profile here

@transaction.atomic
def add_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.save()
            Profile.objects.create(
                user=user,
                first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'],
                #...and other attributes
            )
            messages.success(request, 'user created with username {}'.format(user.username))
            return redirect('list_user')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'add_user.html', {'form': form})```
````

Comment: it's in the document, `from django.db import transaction`

Answer (score 1):

Um, you are already creating the Profile through signals. So why don't you use it like this:

```
def update_user(request, id):
    # Some code
    if form.is_valid():
        phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        location = form.cleaned_data['location']
        image = form.cleaned_data['image']
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user = form.save()
        user.refresh_from_db()
        user.profile.phone = phone
        user.profile.location = location
        user.profile.first_name = first_name
        user.profile.last_name = last_name
        user.profile.image = image
        user.profile.save()
        messages.success(request, ' {}  updated.'.format(user.username))
        return redirect('list_user')
```

I am using [**`refresh_from_db()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db) to reload the object. Because Profile has been created through signals, so refreshing the User object should reload the Profile model.

Comment: i am not being able to create `profile` model  form `RegisterForm` but when i update it gets updated.

Comment: Because they are created by [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/). You have added signals in your implementation(as per question)